# Run mvn install on a cloned repo using chef

Tags: java, git, maven, spring-boot, chef-infra

I've cloned a small webapp onto the client, the next step for me is to get maven to build the war file so that I can run it.  I'm perfectly capable of installing maven and then running the command in an executable block but I was hoping on a cleaner solution.

The documentation for the maven cookbook isn't vast and I can't seem to find anywhere that details how to run maven build commands and the like using it.  It appears to be used more for downloading the dependencies rather than building projects.

Any suggestions how I might achieve this without an 'execute' block ?

Comment: have you check this cookbook https://github.com/RelateIQ-chef/maven

Comment: @glg - yes, unless I missed something - I cant' see anywhere on there that relates to building a project that is currently on the drive.  My exec block works fine btu it doesn't feel very elegant.

Comment: can you post your exec block that works for mvn command?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be an execute resource or a call to shell_out at some point. You could build a custom resource around that to make it look more resource-y but at heart a Maven install is a procedural step, not a convergent step so it's going to be a bit awkward. If you want some background on procedural vs. convergent, I wrote up a guide at https://coderanger.net/thinking/.

That said, just moving forward with an `execute` block is fine. Make sure you consider your idempotence rules, either with a notification or some `not_if`/`only_if` guards.